# Casting, Length, and Multiplication

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting

When using the SQL code below I get the error message "No matching signature for function LENGTH for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: LENGTH(STRING); LENGTH(BYTES) at [3:13]." Is there a way for me to get the length of g_date with it still being in INT64 format? Or, conversely, is it possible to multiply g_date by 100+1 if it is not in INT64 format?

```
SELECT
  deg.MASTER_PERSON_INDEX deg_mpi, deg.G_CIP cip,
  case when length(cast(deg.g_date as int64)) = 8 then deg.g_date
  else cast(deg.g_date as int64)*100+1 end g_date, -- some g_dates were in yyyymm format, fixing it here
  deg.g_ipeds ipeds, 
  '0' deg

FROM
  `graduation_di` deg
WHERE deg.MASTER_PERSON_INDEX is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a column `dates` with integer values. These represent dates. Most of the time the integer has values such as 20220131 as 1st January 2022. This format yyyymmdd is ok to parse, but in some cases the day is missing and the format is yyyymm, e.g. 202211. Then this value shall be multiplied by 100 and one added, thus we obtain the first of this month.

```sql
with tbl as (select * from unnest([20220101,20221231,202211]) dates)
select *,
length(cast(dates as string)) as length,
if(dates<909912,dates*100+1,dates) as corrected
 from tbl
```

In case the `date` column is a string:

```
select length(cast(cast("20220131" as int64) as string)) as length
```